# Production build orderCore is missing

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I had to manually upgrade from 3.2 to 4.2 and because I am developing a Angular library, I could not use the schematics to perform the update.

I have got it working on the development build. We are developing a feature library that targets the checkout (Payment Page and Order Confirmation Page) and it works fine.

With the production build (`ng build --configuration production`), the payment page works fine, but the Order Confirmation page is not working. it complains that `orderCore` feature is not configured properly.

Note: we are being redirected from an external site, back to the order confirmation page (after authorization). When the page loads, it shows the following error in the log and show a broken my account page.

```
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Feature orderCore is not configured properly
    at FacadeFactoryService.getResolver (spartacus-core.js:24825)
    at FacadeFactoryService.create (spartacus-core.js:24867)
    at facadeFactory (spartacus-core.js:24898)
    at orderReturnRequestFacadeFactory (spartacus-order-root.js:13)
    at Object.factory (spartacus-order-root.js:37)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11457)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11276)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25352)
    at Object.get (core.js:25066)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3354)
```

Anyone has an idea if we are missing some configuration in the feature modules?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { checkoutTranslationChunksConfig, checkoutTranslations } from '@spartacus/checkout/assets';
import { CHECKOUT_FEATURE, CheckoutRootModule } from '@spartacus/checkout/root';
import { CmsConfig, I18nConfig, provideConfig } from '@spartacus/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CheckoutRootModule,
  ],
  providers: [provideConfig({
    featureModules: {
      [CHECKOUT_FEATURE]: {
        module: () =>
          import('@spartacus/checkout').then((m) => m.CheckoutModule),
      }
    },
  } as CmsConfig),
    provideConfig({
      i18n: {
        resources: checkoutTranslations,
        chunks: checkoutTranslationChunksConfig,
      },
    } as I18nConfig)
  ]
})
export class CheckoutFeatureModule {
}
```

Comment: Hi Erik. Can you please provide more information: how did you extend the checkout, and how did you bundle it? Did you modify the order library? Do you mind posting some screenshots of the flow (before the place order, redirection to another domain, and after the redirection back to Spartacus? What happens when you are redirected back to Spartacus in development mode? Do you see the order history page, or order confirmation page?

Comment: https://github.com/checkout/Checkout-SAP-Cloud-Commerce-2011/tree/main/js-storefront/checkout-spartacus-connector this is the 3.2 version of the library. We override many components on the payment page, order confirmation page and order history. I have no publicly available version of the 4.x upgrade.

Comment: We are using the standard angular build process for packaging for production.

Comment: We are normally showing the order confirmation page, by overriding the OrderConfirmationGuard, we place the order right after the user comes back to the order confirmation page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague has provided a proposal:

If you want to use Spartacus Order library, you need to create "order-feature.module.ts" for it. And by default core is bundled together with components. So, in your configuration, you need have this set: "[ORDER_CORE_FEATURE]: ORDER_FEATURE". So, the config is something like this:

```js
const config: CmsConfig = {
    featureModules: {
         [ORDER_FEATURE]: {
                cmsComponents: [
                   ....
                ],
          },
        // by default core is bundled together with components
        [ORDER_CORE_FEATURE]: ORDER_FEATURE,
     },
};
```